# gedmo_translatable vs gedmo_translator - StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, stofdoctrineextensions

What are the differences between these two [extensions](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst#add-the-extensions-to-your-mapping) in StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle.

gedmo_translatable
gedmo_translator

Answer (score 2):

Tips from [Doctrine behavioral extensions](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-behavioral-extensions.html), [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md) and [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst) documentations,

**Translatable** gives you a very handy solution for translating records into diferent languages. Put another way, It's a behavioral extension which operate like some of the most commonly used behaviors, leaving the domain objects as clean as possible. Annotations makes it easy to understand an intended behavior of properties on your Entities.

**Translator** - explicit way to handle translations, as an example, here's [the class](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Translator/Entity/Translation.php) used to handle entity/property translation.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand. You do provide very useful documentation but I had seen it before and still don't understand.

When would I need to enable the translator? I am able to get the translatable functionality without the translator. I just don't understand what "explicit way to handle translations" means or how it comes into play?

Answer (score 2):

Here is [a link](http://knplabs.fr/blog/I%28blah...blah...blah%29n) that explains what Translator is exactly (and how it can be better than Translatable in some use cases).